# Where is my Ubuntu OS files located?

Tags: files

I'm running Windows 8.1 box. I chose to install Ubuntu 14.04 "Along Side of Windows." What I want to know is where are the Ubuntu files stored? See the image below.

[image]

### Thank you for your time.

JamesKB

Comment: Your fifth partition from the left (Ext4) has your Ubuntu installation. Your last partition has your Ubuntu swap partition (Linux Swap). Swap space in Linux is used when the amount of physical memory (RAM) is full. Judging from the size of your swap partition, your computer has at least 4GB RAM.

Comment: I have 8GB ram. So can I delete the E:Linux partition and add its space the (Ext4) partition??

Comment: Before you delete anything, browse the E:Linux partition from both Windows and Ubuntu to see if there are any files on it. If you find any files on the E:Linux partition make **backups** of them. Then you can resize your Ubuntu partition: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions/18525#18525 using the GParted application that is on the Ubuntu live DVD/USB.  Be very careful when you resize the Ubuntu partition that you take the space from the E:Linux(NTFS) partition and NOT from one of your Windows partitions!! Check at least 3 times before you apply any changes in GParted.

Comment: How come your e drive has linux and is using ntfs? Can linux run on ntfs? Also EXT4 should have your system files. It's easier if you booted linux and looked at things from there instead of windows, you'll get a better feel of where everything is

Comment: Tatakai - Before I installed Ubuntu I created a new partition, E: and sized it to 419GB and named it Linux. I thought Ubuntu would install into this partition but it did not, rather it took some of its space and created two new partitions, Ext4 and Linus Swap.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu installation (and files) are on the Ext4 partition that is second to last in the image.

[image]